# Better method for sorting BOM?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using VBA in Excel to reorganize the output of the bill of materials(BOM) due to the tree structure being there, but the part numbers are not in a descending order. My first sheet "MasterSheet" has all part numbers of a given machine with a column that has the file names and another column with part numbers and another with its BOM location. The second sheet is "SorterSheet" that will reorder a given assembly, but only one single assembly. I'm having trouble coming up with the logic that will keep the tree structure but still layout a descending part number format for the whole sheet.

Keep in mind there are hundreds of lines of these with multiple assemblies. How do I reorganize the table to keep the tree structure and get the descending part number format?

THE ORIGINAL TABLE...

| LEVEL LOCATION | FILE NAME | PART NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 195700.SLDASM | 195700 |
| 1.1 | 195718.SLDPRT | 195718 |
| 1.2 | 195713.SLDPRT | 195713C |
| 1.3 | 195713.SLDPRT | 195713 |
| 1.4 | 195717.SLDPRT | 195717 |
| 1.5 | 190540.SLDASM | 190540 |
| 1.5.1 | 190539.SLDPRT | 190539 |
| 1.5.2 | 187729.SLDPRT | 187729 |
| 1.7 | 123775.SLDPRT | 123775 |
| 1.8 | 195715.SLDPRT | 195715 |
| 1.9 | 195713.SLDPRT | 195713B |
| 1.10 | 195712.SLDPRT | 195712 |
| 1.11 | 195716.SLDPRT | 195716 |
| 1.13 | 187724.SLDASM | 187724 |
| 1.13.1 | 187725.SLDPRT | 18725 |
| 1.13.2 | 118783.SLDPRT | 118783M |
| 1.13.3 | 187726.SLDPRT | 187726 |
| 1.15 | 111931.SLDPRT | 111931 |
| 1.16 | 195714.SLDPRT | 195714 |
| 1.17 | 195713.SLDPRT | 195713A |
| 1.18 | 195701.SLDASM | 195701 |
| 1.18.1 | 195704.SLDPRT | 195704 |
| 1.18.2 | 195702.SLDPRT | 195702 |
| 1.18.3 | 195729.SLDPRT | 195729 |
| 1.18.4 | 187734.SLDPRT | 187734 |
| 1.18.5 | 195704.SLDPRT | 195704 |
| 1.18.6 | 195704.SLDPRT | 195704 |
| 1.18.7 | 195703.SLDPRT | 195703 |
| 1.18.8 | 187728.SLDPRT | 187728 |
| 1.18.9 | 195725.SLDASM | 195725 |
| 1.18.9.1 | 195730.SLDPRT | 195730 |
| 1.18.9.2 | 140940.SLDPRT | 140940P |
| 1.18.9.3 | 196360.SLDPRT | 196360 |
| 1.18.9.4 | 195728.SLDPRT | 195728 |
| 1.18.10 | 187733.SLDPRT | 187733 |
| 1.18.11 | 195704.SLDPRT | 195708 |
| 1.18.12 | 195704.SLDPRT | 195705 |
| 1.18.13 | 195702.SLDPRT | 195702A |
| 1.18.14 | 187727.SLDPRT | 187727 |
| 1.18.15 | 195710.SLDASM | 195710 |
| 1.18.15.1 | 195711.SLDPRT | 195711 |
| 1.18.15.2 | 187707.SLDPRT | 187707 |
| 1.18.16 | 187732.SLDPRT | 187732 |
| 1.18.17 | 195704.SLDPRT | 195707 |
| 1.19 | 195719.SLDASM | 195719 |
| 1.19.1 | 195720.SLDPRT | 195720 |
| 1.19.2 | 195857.SLDPRT | 195857 |
| 1.19.3 | 195856.SLDPRT | 195856 |
| 1.21 | 187936.SLDPRT | 187936 |

SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS...

| LEVEL LOCATION | FILE NAME | PART NUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 195700.SLDASM | 195700 |
| 1.19 | 195719.SLDASM | 195719 |
| 1.19.2 | 195857.SLDPRT | 195857 |
| 1.19.3 | 195856.SLDPRT | 195856 |
| 1.19.1 | 195720.SLDPRT | 195720 |
| 1.1 | 195718.SLDPRT | 195718 |
| 1.4 | 195717.SLDPRT | 195717 |
| 1.11 | 195716.SLDPRT | 195716 |
| 1.8 | 195715.SLDPRT | 195715 |
| 1.16 | 195714.SLDPRT | 195714 |
| 1.2 | 195713.SLDPRT | 195713C |
| 1.9 | 195713.SLDPRT | 195713B |
| 1.17 | 195713.SLDPRT | 195713A |
| 1.3 | 195713.SLDPRT | 195713 |
| 1.10 | 195712.SLDPRT | 195712 |
| 1.18 | 195701.SLDASM | 195701 |
| 1.18.3 | 195729.SLDPRT | 195729 |
| 1.18.9 | 195725.SLDASM | 195725 |
| 1.18.9.3 | 196360.SLDPRT | 196360 |
| 1.18.9.1 | 195730.SLDPRT | 195730 |
| 1.18.9.4 | 195728.SLDPRT | 195728 |
| 1.18.9.2 | 140940.SLDPRT | 140940P |
| 1.18.15 | 195710.SLDASM | 195710 |
| 1.18.15.1 | 195711.SLDPRT | 195711 |
| 1.18.15.2 | 187707.SLDPRT | 187707 |
| 1.18.5 | 195704.SLDPRT | 195709 |
| 1.18.11 | 195704.SLDPRT | 195708 |
| 1.18.17 | 195704.SLDPRT | 195707 |
| 1.18.6 | 195704.SLDPRT | 195706 |
| 1.18.12 | 195704.SLDPRT | 195705 |
| 1.18.1 | 195704.SLDPRT | 195704 |
| 1.18.7 | 195703.SLDPRT | 195703 |
| 1.18.13 | 195702.SLDPRT | 195702A |
| 1.18.2 | 195702.SLDPRT | 195702 |
| 1.18.4 | 187734.SLDPRT | 187734 |
| 1.18.10 | 187733.SLDPRT | 187733 |
| 1.18.16 | 187732.SLDPRT | 187732 |
| 1.18.8 | 187728.SLDPRT | 187728 |
| 1.18.14 | 187727.SLDPRT | 187727 |
| 1.5 | 190540.SLDASM | 190540 |
| 1.5.1 | 190539.SLDPRT | 190539 |
| 1.5.2 | 187729.SLDPRT | 187729 |
| 1.21 | 187936.SLDPRT | 187936 |
| 1.13 | 187724.SLDASM | 187724 |
| 1.13.3 | 187726.SLDPRT | 187726 |
| 1.13.1 | 187725.SLDPRT | 18725 |
| 1.13.2 | 118783.SLDPRT | 118783M |
| 1.7 | 123775.SLDPRT | 123775 |
| 1.15 | 111931.SLDPRT | 111931 |

Comment: 195700 - 195718 - 195717 that seems off according to your explanation.
Would this be the logic you mean: `=SORTBY(A2:C13,LEFT(C2:C13,6),-1,C2:C13,-1)` ?

Comment: Please share more data 2 , 2.1 , 2.1.1 ... It's helpful to show some of the tree structure pattern.

Comment: 195700 - 195718 - 195717 is actually correct. Level location has the overall assembly as 195700 (which is why it is position 1). All children of that assembly are to follow (i.e. 1.1, 1.2, 1.4,) in a descending order. Every period denotes the children of an assembly. Much like 190539 is an assembly inside of an assembly which is why its 1.5 location has children 1.5.1 and 1.5.2. My current method of sorting is chopping off the left and right of the level location and using a series of if statements to apply the sort which is fine for single assemblies, but not for a whole sheet.

Comment: I've added more data for 50 total lines, I hope this helps. Each subcomponent stays with its respective assembly

Answer (score 0):

The code was tested only against the sample data in OP. It may need updates to handle all variations in the full BOM data.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim Arr, Itm, rData As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        ' Loading data
        Set rData = .Range(.[D1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
        Arr = rData.Value
    End With
    ' auxiliary column
    Arr(1, 4) = "SortKey"
    For i = 2 To UBound(Arr)
        ' the first level
        If InStr(CStr(Arr(i, 1)), ".") = 0 Then
            Arr(i, 4) = "'" & Left(Arr(i, 2), 4) + "999"
        ' part number w/o ending letter
        ElseIf Len(Arr(i, 3)) = 6 Then
            Arr(i, 4) = "'" & Arr(i, 3) & "0"
        ' part number w/ ending letter
        Else
            Arr(i, 4) = "'" & Arr(i, 3)
        End If
    Next
    ' write back
    rData.Value = Arr
    ' Sorting data 
    rData.Sort key1:=Range("D1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
    ' clean auxiliary column if needed
'    Columns(4).Hidden = True
'    rData.Column(4).ClearContents
End Sub
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find an answer at [HERE](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/sort-mixed-multilevel-numbers-text-excel/). I'll have to modify the hierarchy list by extracting the left portion of its location and manually apply its position in a descending order with a sort. Thank you everyone for your input!